# Boost, get UTC time in minutes precision

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I want the UTC time in minutes and I don't want seconds. I am doing...

```
auto timeUTC = boost::posix_time::second_clock::universal_time();
std::cout << to_iso_extended_string(timeUTC) << std::endl;
```

This will print the time as `2020-06-29T23:06:30`

I want the seconds part to be removed form the `ptime` object, example `2020-06-29T23:06:00`.
How do I do this...?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom facet and just drop the "seconds" flag (`%S`) from the format:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"

using boost::posix_time::time_facet;
int main()
{
    auto timeUTC = boost::posix_time::second_clock::universal_time();
    std::cout << "iso extended string: \n\t";
    std::cout << to_iso_extended_string(timeUTC) << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "custom facet: \n\t";
    time_facet* custom_facet = new time_facet("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M");
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), custom_facet)); 
    std::cout << timeUTC << std::endl;
}
```

#### [Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/l7mJCNsdZXZdWkM0)

Output:

```
iso extended string: 
    2020-06-29T19:40:30
custom facet: 
    2020-06-29T19:40
```

You may alternatively use this facet to simply write zeros for the seconds:

```
time_facet* custom_facet = new time_facet("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:00");
```

---

If you are looking to *actually change the internal representation* such that the seconds are zero, you can convert to and from a `tm`:

```
auto as_tm = to_tm(timeUTC);
as_tm.tm_sec = 0;
auto zeroed_seconds = boost::posix_time::ptime_from_tm(as_tm);
```

#### [Live Demo 2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/guaPTWuPu4OU0ZhT)

Answer (score 2):

This will create a ptime with the seconds zeroed out:

```
auto ptimeUtc = boost::posix_time::second_clock::universal_time();
auto date = ptimeUtc.date();
auto time = ptimeUtc.time_of_day();
auto timeRounded = pt::time_duration(time.hours(), time.minutes(), 0);
pt::ptime ptimeUtcRounded(date, timeRounded);
std::cout << to_iso_extended_string(ptimeUtcRounded) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about just removing the last 3 characters of the string?

```
auto timeUTCString = to_iso_extended_string(timeUTC);
std::cout << timeUTCString.substr(0, timeUTCString.length() - 3) << std::endl;
```

Comment: I want the zeroed out data in the ptime object.

Comment: I saw. @AndyG's answer is the way to go.